# How to get count of documents per TLD in Solr core?

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I have a Solr core with a total count of around 20,000 documents.

I get the total number by this query "http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/query?debug=query&q=*:*" from the value of field "numFound".

Now I am trying to get the count of documents based on a URL (Top level domain to be specific) by this query "http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/query?debug=query&q=*:*&group=true&group.field=url" but it groups the same TLD multiple times based on the URL for e.g. "http://www.emro.who.int/contact-us.html" and "http://www.emro.who.int/copyright.html" would be in two different separate groups while I want them to be in the same group based on the TLD i.e. "http://www.emro.who.int/. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You want to create a secondary field that is only the host itself (probably without the protocol as well, unless you want to have separate entries for `http` and `https`). Use a [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/charfilterfactories.html#solr-patternreplacecharfilterfactory) with a regular expression that only leaves the `host` part of the URL. (I don't have a ready definition, otherwise I'd add it as an answer). You can then facet on that field to get the number of documents per host.

Comment: Nutch provides plugins which add fields for that purpose:
(1) the plugin index-more adds the field "host" which will contain "www.emro.who.int", (2) the plugin "tld" adds a field "tld" which will contain "int", and (3) the plugin "index-basic" adds  a field "domain" containing the registered domain "who.int" if the property "indexer.add.domain" is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MatsLindh

Comment: @SebastianNagel Thanks for the answer. I tried this query "http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/query?q=*:*&group=true&group.field=host&group.ngroups=true&fl=url&rows=-1" and it works fine except it has some issues when in some cases for "who.int" it shows TLD ".int" as the host instead "who" and in some cases, for "emro.who.int" it shows subdomain "emro" as host. Any clues?

Comment: That's strange: when running `bin/nutch indexchecker -doIndex -Dindexer.add.domain=true -Dplugin.includes='protocol-okhttp|parse-tika|index-(basic|more|anchor)|tld' https://www.emro.who.int/index.html` I see: tld = "int", domain = "who.int", host = "www.emro.who.int". That's how I would expect it.